# Unknown format error when trying to respond_to format.xml

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to parse a simple XML POST request and send back a 200 status in response but I'm receiving an unknown format error, but I do not understand why. The action says processing as */* not as xml.  Any help would be great!

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:171:in `vz_api'

Started POST "/vz_api" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-25 19:52:27 -0400
Processing by LocationsController#vz_api as */*

  def vz_api
    require 'nokogiri'
    xml_doc = Nokogiri::XML(request.body.read)
    vin = xml_doc.xpath("//VIN").inner_text
    @truck = Truck.find_by(vin: vin)
    @location = @truck.location
    lat = xml_doc.xpath("//Latitude").inner_text
    lng = xml_doc.xpath("//Longitude").inner_text
    heading = xml_doc.xpath("//Heading").inner_text
    speed = xml_doc.xpath("//Speed")[0].inner_text
    @location.update_attributes(longitude: lng, latitude: lat, speed: speed, direction: heading)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml do # format.json
        render :nothing => true, :status => :ok
        # return true
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is processing as */* not XML or JSON, so why don't you try the following instead

Remove respond_to block and just have:

`render :nothing => true, status: :ok`

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean here: `Rails is processing as / not XML or JSON`. What do you mean by this?